# Java Old JRE Installation Issue

Tags: java

At my company, we have an internal application that uses Java. It evidently must use 7.0.5, since the app stops working on machines that have been upgraded to 7.0.7. We have an installer stored on the network here that I was not  initially notified about. Here's the situation.

- Two identical machines: "Laptop A" and "Laptop B"
- I downloaded a copy of jre-7u5 from oldversion.com and installed it on Laptop A.
- Java doesn't run in firefox on Laptop A (according to javatester.org as well as oracle's java site). I have set extensions.blocklist.enabled to "false", and plugins.hide_infobar_for_outdated_plugin to "true"
- I found out about the installer we already had before getting to Laptop B. Seeing as it was already on the NAS, I used it to install on Laptop B, and it works fine. I have uninstalled java on Laptop A, and reinstalled using our "known good" installer, to no avail.

Is there any way I can resolve this? If not, the laptop can be requisitioned for another department, which doesn't use our custom app, but it would be best if I could get it going.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JavaRa](http://singularlabs.com/kb/completely-remove-java-using-singularlabs-javara/) to completely remove all traces of old Java installations:

[image]