# How can I uninstall Java 7 Update 5 when I don't have the "jre1.7.0_05-c.msi" file?

Tags: windows, java, uninstall, windows-installer, jre

Whenever I try to update to the latest version of Java, an installation of Java 7 Update 5 is detected and then I'm asked for the file, ***jre1.7.0_05-c.msi***, which I don't have, so then the installation is cancelled and I'm left unable to upgrade Java.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Also see [Java Old JRE Installation Issue](http://superuser.com/a/483547/138343).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just removed the installation entry by deleting the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\4EA42A62D9304AC4784BF238120750FF` in  **regedit.exe** and I was then able to upgrade Java without any problems.

Answer (score 3):

If possible, download jre1.7, install it, then uninstall.

Check following oracle page for old version of java:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

If you want to get the msi file, you can install it on another computer or get it from another computer that already has it. The file location is at

```
c:Users/<Username>/AppData/LocalLow/Sun/Java/jre1.7
```

Copy it over and give it a try.

Comment: It's not possible since I need to uninstall my existing installation before I can install anything else—it won't install over it.

Comment: What about downloading the latest version and install it?

Comment: That's the version with which I'm having a problem.

Comment: How did you get that one? The current java for windows d/l are jre-7u9-windows-x64.exe and jre-7u9-windows-x64-i586.exe.

Comment: I'm not sure how I got it. Probably either by running jre-7u5-windows-i586.exe or through the Chrome plugin setup (e.g., chromeinstall-7u5.exe). It shows up as "Java(TM) 7 Update 5" in the "Add/Remove Programs" control panel.

Comment: I updated the answer, hope that help.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ihelpforum.com/index.php?guides/problem-uninstalling-java-java-not-working.112/

Use the above guide it helped med to remove java.

Comment: You should add a more detailed solution, instead of just posting a link. Link only answers can easily become useless due link-rot.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by using windows troubleshooter , refer below link to downlad

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed
Click download-> in problem install /uninstall troubleshooter window select product to uninstall and its done.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right; in order to be able to reinstall or upgrade java, without the current install MSI file, remove the corresponding entry from the registry !
just search by yourself, or use a reg file like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; 1.7.5
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\4EA42A62D9304AC4784BF238120750FF]
; 1.7.25
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\4EA42A62D9304AC4784BF238120752FF]
```

play this file and reboot, java is able to install at new !
it would be good to have a reg file containing all of the possibilities for every java version ^^

if it's not sufficient, M$ provides a tool for corrupted installs :
http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall